# syntax error, unexpected 'str_replace' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am getting the error on my code

```
echo "<form action='"str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])"'  method='post'>
```

I tried plenty of things but it is not working for me.

Comment: You need to concatenate the `str_replace` (you missed the dots) and at the end of the string you missed the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<form action='".str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."'  method='post'>";
```